# Can you use a batch script as a Custom sign tool in Advanced Installer?

Tags: code-signing, advanced-installer

In Advanced Installer, I'm trying to set up the files it generates to be digitally signed. In the **Digital Signature** section, **Settings**, I choose "Custom" as the Sign Tool.

There are 2 settings needed to be filled in here: Path and Command Line.

Can I specify a batch script here? If so, how exactly is this specified?

For the "Path" field, I have specified `C:\code\Myproject\setup\signing\sign.bat`

... and in the "Command line" field: `sign.bat <file_name>`

(Yeah I have `sign.bat` in there twice - wasn't sure about this)

(Also I have put in `<file_name>` literally in there as it specifies in the [Advanced Installer User guide](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/digital-signature-settings-tab.html) on the assumption that it's a placeholder for the actual files that are specified in the **Files Configured for Signing** section)

However, when try to build my installer, I get this error:

> The digital signing of the APPDIR\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe file failed. Error message: 'The system cannot find the file specified.
> This is an unknown "signtool.exe" error!
>
> For a possible solution please check our Digital Signature FAQ from:
> [https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/faq-digital-signature.html](https://ttps://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/faq-digital-signature.html)  '

The provided FAQ doesn't appear to show the answer.

Is this possible, and if so what is the correct way to specify it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify a BAT file in the "Path" field. There can be referenced only a "Signtool.exe" executable file.

The command line parameters you configured in the BAT file must be handled and implemented by your own custom built "SignTool.exe" app file.